# Dll error while opening wamp server

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-runtime, runtime-error, wamp

I am trying to run wamp server which was running fine earleir. Getting dllruntime error. By mistake I deleted few updates couldn't recover. Also Windows support for 7 is over so couldn't find files.Here is screen shot of installed v c .
[Scrrenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0odoglu78anu54n/1.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: See the WAMPServer alternative repo, there is an install (at the bottom) which will install all the required MSVC Runtimes all in one simple install. [WAMPServer ALternate repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Or pick the ones you deleted one by one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Hi i downloaded zip files 32bit but showing same error.

Comment: Which updates did you delete exactly? Are yu talking about Windows Updates?

Comment: @Riggsfolly probably yes. As was getting window build error...As I don't update Windows

Comment: In real mess .....

Comment: And which version of WAMPServer are you trying to install

Comment: What do you mean by a _windows build error_

Comment: Then I think you have just messed up windows.

Comment: But a genuine version of windows and then you can keep it fully updated

Comment: @RiggsFolly Finally fixed it.Got it....missing update KB2999226